# Laravel Multiple Image Upload via API

Tags: php, laravel, api

I am creating a media API for the first time creating an API.

I have this code:

```
/**
* Store a newly created resource in storage.
*
* @param  \App\Http\Requests\UploadRequest $request
* @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
*/
public function store(UploadRequest $request)
{
    if(!$request->hasFile('fileName')) {
        return response()->json(['upload_file_not_found'], 400);
    }
    $file = $request->file('fileName');
    if(!$file->isValid()) {
        return response()->json(['invalid_file_upload'], 400);
    } 

    if($request->hasfile('fileName'))
    {
        $media = new Media();
        $data = array();
        foreach($request->file('fileName') as $image)
        {
            $rdm = uniqid(5);
            $name= $rdm .'-'.$image->getClientOriginalName();
            $image->move(public_path().'/images/', $name);
            $data[] = $name;

        }

        $media->fileName = json_encode($data);
        $media->clientId = $request->clientId;
        $media->uploadedBy = Auth::user()->id;
        $media->save();

    }

    return ["success" => "Your media file has been successfully uploaded"];
}
```

Please can you help me why it doesn't upload the images into the public path. It also doesn't store anything in the database. I get a 200 code from postman when sending my POST request, however the database has an empty array as the fileName?

**** EDIT ****

I am uploading multiple images. There isnt a form for this as i am making an api for a mobile app. The request is a POST request to URL /api/v1/media

Comment: are you uploading multiple images?

Comment: @LuckySaini I am yes, i have updated my post now :)

Comment: Can you add the HTML of your form?

Comment: @StevenHardy check `public/images` directory permission. This should be writable directory.

Comment: What is your request type? I mean it should be formData

Comment: @T.Altena there isnt a HTML form as i want to create the api for a mobile app :)

Comment: @LuckySaini I will check this and come back to you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution i come up with that works :)

This uploads multiple files and checks the extension for valid files.

```
public function store(UploadRequest $request)
{
    if(!$request->hasFile('fileName')) {
        return response()->json(['upload_file_not_found'], 400);
    }

    $allowedfileExtension=['pdf','jpg','png'];
    $files = $request->file('fileName'); 
    $errors = [];

    foreach ($files as $file) {      

        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $check = in_array($extension,$allowedfileExtension);

        if($check) {
            foreach($request->fileName as $mediaFiles) {
                $media = new Media();
                $media_ext = $mediaFiles->getClientOriginalName();
                $media_no_ext = pathinfo($media_ext, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                $mFiles = $media_no_ext . '-' . uniqid() . '.' . $extension;
                $mediaFiles->move(public_path().'/images/', $mFiles);
                $media->fileName = $mFiles;
                $media->clientId = $request->clientId;
                $media->uploadedBy = Auth::user()->id;
                $media->save();
            }
        } else {
            return response()->json(['invalid_file_format'], 422);
        }

        return response()->json(['file_uploaded'], 200);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    if ($this->getErrorIfAny($request->all(), $this->ruls)) {
        return $this->getErrorIfAny($request->all(), $this->ruls);
    }

    if (!$request->hasFile('image_url')) {
        return response($this->getResponseFail(trans('my_keywords.uploadFileNotFound'), false), 400);
    }

    $allowedfileExtension = ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg'];

    $files = $request->file('image_url');

    $number_photos_upload = count($files);

    $pictures_available_upload = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++) {
        $extension = $files[$i]->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $check = in_array($extension, $allowedfileExtension);

        if ($check) {
            $pictures_available_upload[$i] = $files[$i];
        }
    }

    $number_images_success_uploded = 0;

    $images_urls = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($pictures_available_upload); $i++) {

        $image = $pictures_available_upload[$i];

        $path = config('paths.storage_path') .
            $image->store(config('paths.store_image_path'), 'public');

        //store image file into directory and db
        $store_images = new StoreImages();
        $store_images['store_id'] = $request['store_id'];
        $store_images['image_url'] = $path;
        $result = $store_images->save();
        if ($result) {
            $images_urls[$i] = $path;
            $number_images_success_uploded = $number_images_success_uploded + 1;
        }
    }

    if ($number_images_success_uploded == 0) {
        return response($this->getResponseFail(trans('my_keywords.invalidFileFormat'), false), 422);
    } else {
        $data = [
            'store_id' => (int) $request['store_id'],
            'number_photos_upload' => $number_photos_upload,
            'number_images_success_uploded' => $number_images_success_uploded,
            'images' => $images_urls,
        ];
        return response($this->getResponse(__('my_keywords.operationSuccessfully'), true, $data), 200);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score -1):

send as binary for api .

[php file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)